# How to create user group programmatically?

Tags: joomla-3.5, user-groups

I want to new a user group by php, I think there should be an API ready but I just can't find an example code by google. 
I have the parent group name and ID, and the new group title is ready, what object should I get and how to create the new user group?
If there is no API for this, I might just access the #_Usergroups, but I am worry I'll mess uo the lft, rgt columns. 
If someone could show me, or have any other suggestions, an example cold would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the group by directly invoking the save function in com_users component model.

```
$group = array('id'=>0, 'title'=>'Group Title', 'parent_id'=>1);
JLoader::import('joomla.application.component.model');
JLoader::import('group', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_users/models');
$groupModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance( 'Group', 'UsersModel' );

if(! $groupModel->save($group) )
{
   JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($groupModel->getError());
   return false;
}
```